# recovering deleted partition from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I have started learning Kafka and have a naïve question. Lets have a scenario where we have 5 node cluster with a topic having one partition and 3 replicas. Broker-0 has the leader partition, Broker-1 has a follower partition and Broker-2 has a follower partition. Now, if one of the broker containing the follower partition crashes, we are left with one leader and one follower. My question is, If we add another node to the cluster, how to recover the failed follower partition. Is there a way to get back the follower partition once we add a new broker to the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As yours is a 5 node cluster, as soon as one of the node that contains your topic's follower partition crashes , none of the remaining 2 nodes will become the new follower, as automatic follower creation doesn't happen in Kafka.

e.g. TopicA Partition1 - (node1 - leader , node2 - follower , node3 - follower)

Let's assume node2 crashes , in this case your TopicA Partition1 will remain under replicated unless a node with same node id is spin up or partitions are re-distributed manually using partition reassignment tool.

Comment: If the partition is an under replicated partition, does that mean the producer will no longer be able to send messages?

Comment: @zil If you've disabled unclean leader election, it's not possible for under replicated partitions to be produced to since they cannot be the leader. Also this answer isn't correct since new (or old) nodes do not automatically take over replicas

Comment: @OneCricketeer - You are correct, I've updated the details. In case of both addition and deletion of node, partition redistribution doesn't happen. It just moves the leader around, in case of a leader replica crashed. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In order for new or old nodes to take over the missing replica, you'll need to run [`kafka-reassign-partitions` tool](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_automigrate)

> The partition reassignment tool can [...] be used to selectively move replicas of a partition to a specific set of brokers

Or you could simply recover the failed broker on its own rather than "expand" the cluster (assuming you're giving the new node its own unique broker ID)